# SavedInstanceState devuelve Null

Tags: java

Me da este error en particular `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`, la aplicacion crashea al ejecutar Run MainActivity , he debuggeado el programa y me devuelve savedInstanceState como Null

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText dato1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText dato2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final Button boton_enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    final RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);



    boton_enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        String v1 = dato1.getText().toString();
        String v2 = dato2.getText().toString();

        int operador1 = Integer.parseInt(v1);
        int operador2 = Integer.parseInt(v2);
        final double suma = operador1 + operador2;
        final double resta = operador1 - operador2;
        final double multiplicacion = operador1 * operador2;
        final double division = operador1 / operador2;

        public void onClick(View v) {

                           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);

                           if (rb1.isSelected()) {
                               intent.putExtra("suma",suma);

                           } else if (rb2.isSelected()) {

                               intent.putExtra("resta",resta);
                           } else if (rb3.isSelected()) {
                               intent.putExtra("mult",multiplicacion);

                           } else if (rb4.isSelected()) {
                               intent.putExtra("divicion",division);


                           }
                           startActivity(intent);



            }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: fijate si alguno de los findViewById() te está devolviendo null porque el id que estás pasando no está en el layout que estás usando

Comment: Tendria que usar el debugger? edit: me aparece savedInstanceState como Null